# Perl 5 - How does this script work and what is @_ and $_?

Tags: perl, grep, quicksort, splice

I'm trying to figure out what's going on in this Perl Script. **The Comments are me thinking**, thank you, if you devote your time helping me. I have very little experience with Perl but have some knowledge in shell scripting.

I think `@_` is a list of parameters passed down in a subroutine and `$_` a global variable, I struggle to make sense of their actual purpose in this script.

```
#!/bin/perl
sub quick_sort {
    # exit condition, when subset contains less than 2 elements
    return @_ if @_ < 2; 

    # choosing pivot element, using subset as input, rand as random offset, no idea what the 1 is for, man says "int fd_out"
    my $p = splice @_, int rand @_, 1;

    # actual recursion and the main source of my confusion
    # calling quicksort(smaller pivot, pivot, quicksort(greater pivot))
    quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @_), $p, quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @_);
}

# running the damn thing, no greater secrets here, i guess 
my @a = (4, 65, 2, -31, 0, 99, 83, 782, 1);
@a = quick_sort @a;

print "@a\n";
```

Comment: The `1` is the third argument to `splice`. See `perldoc -f splice`.

Comment: `@_` is indeed the list (well, array) of parameters. See `perldoc -v '@_'`.

Comment: Is the `perl` executable in `/bin` on your system? It's more commonly `/usr/bin/perl`. (On some systems, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same directory, but `#!/usr/bin/perl` is likely to be more portable.)

Comment: [`perldoc perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @_), $p, quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @_);
```

Let's break this down:

`@_` is the array of function arguments.

`$_` is a temporary scalar variable used as a placeholder in some contexts.

```
grep $_ < $p, @_
```

This is an expression which uses the [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) builtin function to create a list consisting of all the elements from `@_` which satisfy the condition `$_ < $p` -- that is, all the elements which are numerically less than the pivot.

The resulting list is passed to `quick_sort`, so the result is a sorted list of all the elements less than the pivot.

The same thing happens on the other side:

```
quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @_);
```

This takes all the elements of `@_` which are greater than the pivot and sorts those.

Finally:

```
quick_sort(grep $_ < $p, @_), $p, quick_sort(grep $_ >= $p, @_);
```

The comma expression creates a list consisting of:

1. A sorted list of all the arguments less than the pivot element.
2. The pivot element.
3. A sorted list of all the arguments greater than the pivot element.

And when you put those all together, you end up with a sorted list of all the arguments to the function.

But this is all silly. Perl has a builtin `sort` function; you could express the same thing much more concisely as `@a = sort { $a <=> $b } @a`, and it'd actually be much faster.